# Why are the bottom and top texts not centered in 3D Cuboid

Tags: html, css, 3d, center, text-align

This is the code that makes a cuboid, colours it and is supposed to center the text for each side in the center of each side, however it doesnt seem to include the top and bottom sides - text is squished right up to the edge. Why is this and how is it fixed? I'm not sure where I have made my mistake.

```
.scene {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  perspective:500px;
}
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-50px);
  text-align:center;
  line-height:200px;
  font-size:2.5em;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  animation: spin 6s;
}
.box-face {
  position:absolute;
}
.front, .back {
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
}
.right, .left {
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  left:100px;
}
.top, .bottom {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  top:50px;
}
.front {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  transform:rotateY(0deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.right {
  background-color:rgba(255,0,255,0.7);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}
.back {
  background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.7);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.left {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.7);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
}
.top {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.7);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.bottom {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.7);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px)
}
```

```
<div class="scene">
<div class="box">
<div class ="box-face front">front</div>
<div class="box-face back">back</div>
<div class="box-face right">right</div>
<div class="box-face left">left</div>
<div class="box-face top">top</div>
<div class="box-face bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add relevent html code.

Comment: @Rayees AC Done